# Blocking email sending for some users

Tags: apex, community, email, configuration

I want to disable the ability of sending emails for some set of users. can you please let me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some further clarification. Do you wish to block emails being sent to particular users from all possible emails from a Salesforce instance, or only from particular Apex code?

Comment: i have a requirement that some set of users shouldnt be able to send emails. not through code, only for some users i should block email sending functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permission Sets is the way to go.

Disable the Send Email permission for all user profiles.
Create a Permission Set with Send Email = True.
Assign this permission set to the users you want to be able to email.

Comment: I did that but if i go to any account and in activity related list if i click send email with some dummy text. i am able to send email.

Comment: I'm not sure where your issue is as I have replicated the steps and Send an Email was not available to the user without the Send Emails permission set. Did you login as the restricted test user to check the functionality?